# Matrix L1 norm as a minimum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, normed-spaces

The L1 norm is defined for a complex matrix $M$ with coefficients $[m_{ij}]$ as $\|M\|_1 = \sum_{i,j} |m_{ij}|$. I have encountered the following formula for the L1 norm:

$$ \|M\|_1 = \min \sum_{i,j} \|x_i\|_1 \|y_j\|_1 \text{ s.t. } M = \sum_{i,j} x_i y^*_j $$

where the minimization is over all complex vectors, $^*$ denotes conjugate transpose, and $\|x_i\|_1$ is the standard vector L1 norm.

I am confused about how to show that the formula really gives the L1 norm. Clearly, we can take the $x_i$'s and $y_j$'s such that $ \|x_i\|_1 \|y_j\|_1 = |m_{ij}|$ (choose the basis vectors scaled by the corresponding coefficients), which means that LHS $\geq$ RHS. However, why is this choice optimal? I don't understand how I can show that there does not exist a different decomposition $M = \sum_{i,j} x_i y^*_j$ which gives a lower value in the minimization.

Comment: Is there a typo in $M=\sum_ix_iy^*_j$? Should that $j$ be an $i$? Or was that supposed to be a double sum?

Comment: @AlexR. It is a double sum. Thanks for pointing it out.